# Centos 7 & Azure: ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out

Tags: centos, ssh, security, azure

I'm trying to acces one of my recently deployed azure machines via SSH. When i try to do so i am getting the error: ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out. I have not been able to acces this server before using this way however i am able to connect to the server using the serial console so i can change configuration in this machine.

I have checked the ssh_config and the sshd_config and compared them to a working machine and these all seem to be correct. The hosts.allow and hosts.deny are empty but when i add sshd: All to hosts.Allow it has no effect.

The azure firewall allows for usage of port 22 and Firewalld and Selinux have been disabled. Iptables does not seem to be relevant in Centos 7 but has been disabled anyway.

Executing a azure redeploy, reset password, reset ssh public key or a reset configuration have no effect as does the creation of a new azure vdi.

using "tail -f /var/log/secure" or "tail -f /var/log/messages" produced no results.

results of ssh lstoep001@10.61.123.17 -v :

```
OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.61.123.17 [10.61.123.17] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/lstoep001/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /Users/lstoep001/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/lstoep001/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/lstoep001/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/lstoep001/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/lstoep001/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/lstoep001/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/lstoep001/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/lstoep001/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/lstoep001/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.8
```

After using command /usr/sbin/sshd -ddd -D -e:

```
[lstoep]@nl-zwescijelv001 ~]$ sudo /usr/sbin/sshd -ddd -D -e
debug2: load_server_config: filename /etc/ssh/sshd_config
debug2: load_server_config: done config len = 737
debug2: parse_server_config: config /etc/ssh/sshd_config len 737
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:23 setting HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:25 setting HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:26 setting HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:33 setting SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:48 setting AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:66 setting PasswordAuthentication yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:70 setting ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:80 setting GSSAPIAuthentication yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:81 setting GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:97 setting UsePAM yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:103 setting X11Forwarding yes
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:114 setting ClientAliveInterval 180
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:128 setting AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:129 setting AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:130 setting AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:131 setting AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
debug3: /etc/ssh/sshd_config:134 setting Subsystem sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:1+4l5FdG3yg7Z7rYhzkLh09GEd+1kpVKKMW6wC+9EGc
debug1: private host key #1: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:iqOcTP3JTv15EQ6rKGocP2jmP0Z0QQ4c/404sTXcTzI
debug1: private host key #2: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:hcEchCo/rbt56TVziD51gLls8vl2GOZxILy/xMldo8I
debug1: rexec_argv[0]='/usr/sbin/sshd'
debug1: rexec_argv[1]='-ddd'
debug1: rexec_argv[2]='-D'
debug1: rexec_argv[3]='-e'
debug3: oom_adjust_setup
debug1: Set /proc/self/oom_score_adj from 0 to -1000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Bind to port 22 on 0.0.0.0.
Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
debug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: sock_set_v6only: set socket 4 IPV6_V6ONLY
debug1: Bind to port 22 on ::.
Server listening on :: port 22.

===========After trying to connect===============

debug3: fd 5 is not O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Server will not fork when running in debugging mode.
debug3: send_rexec_state: entering fd = 8 config len 737
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 0
debug3: send_rexec_state: done
debug1: rexec start in 5 out 5 newsock 5 pipe -1 sock 8
debug3: recv_rexec_state: entering fd = 5
debug3: ssh_msg_recv entering
debug3: recv_rexec_state: done
debug2: parse_server_config: config rexec len 737
debug3: rexec:23 setting HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
debug3: rexec:25 setting HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
debug3: rexec:26 setting HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
debug3: rexec:33 setting SyslogFacility AUTHPRIV
debug3: rexec:48 setting AuthorizedKeysFile .ssh/authorized_keys
debug3: rexec:66 setting PasswordAuthentication yes
debug3: rexec:70 setting ChallengeResponseAuthentication no
debug3: rexec:80 setting GSSAPIAuthentication yes
debug3: rexec:81 setting GSSAPICleanupCredentials no
debug3: rexec:97 setting UsePAM yes
debug3: rexec:103 setting X11Forwarding yes
debug3: rexec:114 setting ClientAliveInterval 180
debug3: rexec:128 setting AcceptEnv LANG LC_CTYPE LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME LC_COLLATE LC_MONETARY LC_MESSAGES
debug3: rexec:129 setting AcceptEnv LC_PAPER LC_NAME LC_ADDRESS LC_TELEPHONE LC_MEASUREMENT
debug3: rexec:130 setting AcceptEnv LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_ALL LANGUAGE
debug3: rexec:131 setting AcceptEnv XMODIFIERS
debug3: rexec:134 setting Subsystem sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server
debug1: sshd version OpenSSH_7.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: private host key #0: ssh-rsa SHA256:1+4l5FdG3yg7Z7rYhzkLh09GEd+1kpVKKMW6wC+9EGc
debug1: private host key #1: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:iqOcTP3JTv15EQ6rKGocP2jmP0Z0QQ4c/404sTXcTzI
debug1: private host key #2: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:hcEchCo/rbt56TVziD51gLls8vl2GOZxILy/xMldo8I
debug1: inetd sockets after dupping: 3, 3
Connection from 10.35.4.54 port 63036 on 10.61.123.17 port 22
```

content of /var/log/secure:

```
Feb 26 06:41:50 nl-zwescijelv001 sudo: lstoep : TTY=ttyS0 ; PWD=/home/lstoep ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl stop sshd
Feb 26 06:41:50 nl-zwescijelv001 polkitd[532]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:32054:5611464 (system bus name :1.2646 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent--notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Feb 26 06:41:50 nl-zwescijelv001 sshd[869]: Received signal 15; terminating.
Feb 26 06:41:50 nl-zwescijelv001 polkitd[532]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:32054:5611464 (system bus name :1.2646, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Feb 26 06:42:18 nl-zwescijelv001 sudo: lstoep : TTY=ttyS0 ; PWD=/home/lstoep ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd
Feb 26 06:44:59 nl-zwescijelv001 sudo: lstoep : TTY=ttyS0 ; PWD=/home/lstoep ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd
Feb 26 06:45:17 nl-zwescijelv001 sudo: lstoep : TTY=ttyS0 ; PWD=/home/lstoep ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd
Feb 26 06:47:39 nl-zwescijelv001 sudo: lstoep : TTY=ttyS0 ; PWD=/home/lstoep ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd -D -e
Feb 26 06:49:35 nl-zwescijelv001 sudo: lstoep : TTY=ttyS0 ; PWD=/home/lstoep ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd -D -e
Feb 26 06:50:22 nl-zwescijelv001 sudo: lstoep : TTY=ttyS0 ; PWD=/home/lstoep ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start sshd
Feb 26 06:50:22 nl-zwescijelv001 polkitd[532]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:32350:5662674 (system bus name :1.2675 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent--notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8)
Feb 26 06:50:22 nl-zwescijelv001 sshd[32356]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Feb 26 06:50:22 nl-zwescijelv001 sshd[32356]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Feb 26 06:50:22 nl-zwescijelv001 polkitd[532]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:32350:5662674 (system bus name :1.2675, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_US.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
Feb 26 06:51:08 nl-zwescijelv001 sudo: lstoep : TTY=ttyS0 ; PWD=/home/lstoep ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/tail -f /var/log/secure
Feb 26 06:51:37 nl-zwescijelv001 sudo: lstoep : TTY=ttyS0 ; PWD=/home/lstoep ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/tail -n 100 /var/log/secure
```

Comment: Check your Azure firewall again.

Comment: Have done so a few times and port 22 is specifically allowed for all devices in this subnet. Also in the -v log it states: "Connection established" so i would assume that it got through the firewall. What do you think i missed?

Comment: I think I would run sshd in debugging mode to see if any more useful information comes out.

Comment: contains liddle additional info. Option used: -vvv
OpenSSH_7.8p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 10.61.130.17 is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to 10.61.130.17 [10.61.130.17] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.

Comment: That's ssh, not sshd.

Comment: Apologies. I changed the ticket to reflect the debug of sshd and included the content of /var/log/secure

Answer (score 0):

Well it appears that you cannot trust anyone. I talked to the firewall guys and they showed that the server dropped our requests and were adament that it concerned an issue on the machine which i continued to work on for a week. 
After much insistence i got them to open the ssh port and the whole thing worked flawlessly.

Comment: You surely can't trust the firewall guys!